# ¿Cómo utilizar una propiedad abstracta de una clase abstracta en un Controlador?

Tags: c#, clase-abstracta

estoy teniendo el siguiente inconveniente:

Quiero llamar una propiedad abstracta de una clase abstracta en un Controlador, tengo lo siguiente:

**Controlador en el cual quiero llamar a la propiedad abstracta:**

```
public class UnoController : Controller
{  
    // propiedad llamada de la clase abstracta.
}
```

**Clase abstracta con la propiedad a llamar:**

```
public abstract class WebProgramExtension : IProgramExtension
{       
    public abstract string Nombre { get; }
}
```

La propiedad que quiero llamar es Nombre.

¿Cómo puedo llamarla en mi Controlador UnoController?

Comment: Lo que queres hacer es crear una instancia? No se entiende el problema

Answer (score 0):

Si revisamos la documentacion

[abstract (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Esta nos dice:

> El modificador abstract indica que lo que se modifica carece de implementación o tiene una implementación incompleta

O sea no hay una implementacion de esa clase, por lo tanto deberias definir

```
  public class WebProgramXX : WebProgramExtension {

     public override string Nombre 
     { 
        get { return "XX"; } 
     }

  }
```

Desde el controler lo instancias y accedes a su valor

```
public class UnoController : Controller
{  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        WebProgramXX obj = new WebProgramXX();
        ViewBag.Nombre = obj.Nombre;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda una clase abstracta es una subclase, o clase base, y esta no puede
ser instanciada, asi que debes crear una clase derivada, la propiedad abstracta
la puedes sobreescribir.

```
public class ProgramExtension:WebProgramExtension 
{
   ProgramExtension(string nombre){
   _nombre=nombre;
}

 string _nombre;
 public override string Nombre{get{return _nombre;}}
 public string OtraPropiedad{};
}
```

Ya solo resta que la instancies en tu controlador y llames la propiedad.
Saludos